# How can the product of $\sqrt{x}$ be negative?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I've recently implementing my own raytracer in C.

I was reading up some paper on ray-sphere intersection from [http://www.cs.unc.edu/~rademach/xroads-RT/RTarticle.html](http://www.cs.unc.edu/%7Erademach/xroads-RT/RTarticle.html) and this came up:

> $d = \sqrt{r^2 - (c^2 - v^2)}$

> To determine whether an intersection occurs, we compute the value of $d$. If $d >= 0$, then a valid intersection occurs. If the ray does not intersect, then d will be less than zero.

How can the value of $d$ be ever negative from  a square root?

I assume that the paper meant is:

> If $r^2 - (c^2 - v^2) >= 0$, then a valid intersection occurs. If the ray does not intersect, then $r^2 - (c^2 - v^2)$ be less than zero.

But I'm not sure with this assumption as I'm still new in math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes indeed, they did mean what you suggest. You can see this in the pseudocode that immediately follows:

```
v = dot_product( EO, V )
disc = r2 - ((dot_product( EO, EO ) - v2 )
if ( disc < 0 )
    no intersection
else
    d = sqrt( disc )
    P = E + (v - d) * V
```

You can convince yourself that this is correct in the following way. Look at the given diagram:[image]

The ray doesn't intersect with the circle precisely when $b$ is greater than $r$. In this case, we see that $d^2 = r^2-b^2 \leq 0$, so that must be the right condition.

Comment: I immediately stopped reading the paper when it explained $d$ can be negative, so I never even get to read the code as I was stucked interpreting what was written. But even if I read the code, I would still be confuse that the two of them contradict with one another.

Comment: Yes, it's usually a good idea to keep reading a bit when you see something that looks wrong. I've edited my answer to include a bit more reasoning about *why* it should say $d^2$ instead of $d$.